# Can't get conditional to work for dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I am trying to get a dropdown list to show with React but I am having problems with this current set of code. It is supposed to hide the menu on click of the menu button and when clicked outside of the target. What am I doing wrong?

```
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.container = React.createRef();
    this.state = state;
    let state = {
        open: false,
      };
}

handleButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        open: !state.open,
      };
    });
};
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
}

handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (this.container.current && !this.container.current.contains(event.target)){
      this.setState({
        open: false,
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: the error that i get is that it cannot read property of 'current' of undefined

Comment: I can't understand your constructor. What's going on there?

Comment: well it was off of what the website i needed to do. But basically its creating the container variable so that i can have an event listener that closes the menu when clicked out of the container of the list. and setting state to false so the menu can be toggled

Comment: `this.state = state; let state = { open: false };` - I can't understand this. just `this.state={open:false}`

Comment: ok changed the
'this.container = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            open:false
        };'

Comment: how did you catch the click event outside the container?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i found works for me
constructor() {
    super();

```
this.state = {
  showMenu: false,
};

this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
```

}

showMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

```
this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
});
```

}

closeMenu(event) {

```
if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

  this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
  });  

}
```

}